# Using Spring Boot web application to send email notifications via Ionos webmail SMTP not working

Tags: email, smtp

I have created a marketplace application which sends emails to users for various reasons, for example login or order confirmation. Everything works great when I send emails from Gmail but I can't get it working using the website's info email as a sender which is Ionos webmail.

application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.ionos.co.uk
spring.mail.port=587 (also tried 25 here)
spring.mail.username=****
spring.mail.password=****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

This just doesn't work - no error or anything.

When I use 25 as port, I get this:

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1832)
... 103 more
```

DNS

```
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.1and1.com    Domain Connect  

MX  @   mx00.ionos.co.uk    Mail    

MX  @   mx01.ionos.co.uk    Mail    

CNAME   autodiscover    adsredir.ionos.info Mail    

A   @   77.68.9.60  -   

A   www 77.68.9.60  -
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am also using Apache reverse proxy with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to send message to address which domain has not MX record. I think you get server response with this error. This issue is not on the client side.